# how to use group by on this table

Tags: sql-server-2008

here is a screen shot of my table

[image]

I am trying to remove all those rows whose sum of **PostAmt** comes to be 0 when grouped by the **sales_contract_nbr** and the **name**.

for example :

the **sales_contract_nbr** 51101008103 will be removed when grouped by name and sales_contract_nbr as -96.83 and 96.83 when summed up amounts to 0.

Quite simple right?

but what I want apart from this is that I want to remove the contracts in group. I mean if the contract **51101008195** is grouped it amounts to be **533.87** which won't be removed (highlighted)

But I want to remove it in groups

for example
two rows of contract number **51101008195** should be summed first (see the image below) I mean the amount **-533.87** and **533.87** should be summed to get the total of **0**. Only one record for the contract should be left.

[image]

**Update**

More Description :

[image]

what i want to do is first group the row number 1 and 2 (matching amounts one positive and the other negative) and then group the others. If there were 4 rows of the same contract number then the row 1 and row 2 should have been grouped then the row 3 and row 4 should be grouped if there absolute amounts are same if not the row number 3 and 4 doesn't get deleted.

[image]

I want to use group by to eliminate the rows whose total ends up to be 0 and which have the same name or the contract number.

I hope I have made the question clear. If not please ask.

how can it be done?

what i am doing till now is :

```
SELECT sales_contract_nbr
,name
,SUM(PostAmt) PostAmt
FROM tblMasData 
GROUP BY sales_contract_nbr, name
```

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean in the second part of your question ? Can you rephrase it ?

Comment: Which output do you want for line 3 and 4 ? Two lines (3 and 4) or one line with the sum of both PostAmt values ?

Comment: What if you have line 1 = 100 ; line 2 = 100 and line 3 = -200 ? Do you want to hide all three lines ?

Comment: yes all the three lines will be hidden. all I want to do is eliminate any value whose sum comes out to be 0. please help

Comment: And in this case : line 1 = 100, line 2 = -150, line 3 = 75, do you want to display all 3 lines, or only one line with 25 (result of the sum) ?

Comment: all three lines will e displayed in this case.

Comment: That's what I feared. There's no evident solution to compare multiple data and determine which combination might equal to zero. What can be done however quite easily is to hide couples of lines which sum equals to zero. I edited my answer. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I come up with for now :

```
SELECT location
    ,sales_contract_nbr
    ,name
    ,SUM(absPostAmt * nbPostAmt) / ABS(SUM(nbPostAmt)) PostAmt
    ,ABS(SUM(nbPostAmt)) nbPostAmt
    ,SUM(absPostAmt * nbPostAmt) PostAmtTotal
FROM ( 
    SELECT location
        ,sales_contract_nbr
        ,name
        ,PostAmt
        ,ABS(PostAmt) absPostAmt
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN PostAmt >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) nbPostAmt
    FROM tblMasData 
    GROUP BY location
        ,sales_contract_nbr
        ,name
        ,PostAmt
        ,ABS(PostAmt)
) t
GROUP BY location
    ,sales_contract_nbr
    ,name
    ,absPostAmt
HAVING SUM(absPostAmt * nbPostAmt) != 0
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6449ce/12).

This doesn't totally answer your question, as if you have 100 + 100 - 200 for instance, it won't hide all three rows. But it can be pretty messy to find combinations which equal to 0 among a bunch of rows.

More, if some rows have the same amount, they will be grouped. That's why I added a column counting those rows being equal, and a column summing them up at the end.

This should at least allow you to deal with the data programmatically.

Let me know if this fills your needs, or if you need some improvement (which could involve some not so pretty SQL).